# p:commandButton denying another p:commandButton

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

First off let me say I'm at most an intermediate JSF coder.
Now I have an odd problem with some primefaces buttons in my current project and it's really starting to get to me.

The environment is creating a football match.

I have 3 lists of players. The idea is that the user selects a player from the first list and then presses either the "Benched" button to add the player to the benched list or the "Starting" button to pick a player position and then add the player to the starting list.

(I would post a picture but I'm not allowed to :( )

Now my issue is that whenever I use the "Starting" button it renders the "Benched" button completely useless (I get no errors but the action method is not called). So I can add as many players to the bench to start with but as soon as i press the "Starting" button I can't bench more players. I can still use the "Starting" button though.

Here's my code:

```
<h:form id="matchForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="updatePlayers">
        <div class="myContainer">
            <div class="myMatchBox">
                <h:outputLabel value="Pick a player:" />
                <p:selectOneListbox styleClass="heightClassPick myEditMatchPlayers myPickListOnEditMatches" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{manageMatchesBean.geteAllUsablePlayersOne()}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.split('#')[0]} - #{p.split('#')[2]}" itemValue="#{p}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{manageMatchesBean.changeEPickedPlayerOne}" immediate="true"/>
                </p:selectOneListbox>
                <h:outputLabel style="display:block;" value="Add it to:" />
                <p:commandButton styleClass="myMatchCommandButton" value="Starting" update="posdlg0table" oncomplete="PF('posdlg0').show();return false;"/>
                <p:dialog header="Choose a position" widgetVar="posdlg0" modal="true" minHeight="40" resizable="false">
                    <h:dataTable id="posdlg0table" value="#{manageMatchesBean.getPickedPlayerPositionsOne()}" var="pos">
                        <h:column>
                            <p:commandButton value="#{pos.split('#')[0]}" update=":matchForm:updatePlayers" action="#{manageMatchesBean.eAddToStartingOne(pos.split('#')[1])}" process="@this" oncomplete="PF('posdlg0').hide();"/>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                </p:dialog>
                <p:commandButton styleClass="myMatchCommandButton" value="Benched" update=":matchForm:updatePlayers" action="#{manageMatchesBean.eAddToBenchedOne()}" process="@this"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

If I'm missing something or you want to see the java code let me know and I'll post it aswell.

I'm desperate!

Thanks in advance.

- Alex

Comment: 'Completely useless' is an enduser experience. As a developer you can check lots of things. Errors, network traffic, css/modal related things etc...

Comment: I get no errors and the action of the button is not called. Maybe I should've put that in the description.

Comment: Well, you do open a modal dialog, so that prevents the other button to be used...

Comment: Yes that is true. But the dialog is closed again. And it is after that I can't use the Benched button anymore.

Comment: Look att css stuff... is there still a modal 'layer' that is not removed or whatever... Please take a closer look as a DEVELOPER

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I solved it.. After several hours of trying to fix this I quit and wrote this question here and within 1 hour of writing it I found a tiny mistake in my java code. And yes apparently the method was called. Anyway. Now it works. Thanks.